# Reporte con Openpyxl en Django

Tags: python, django, openpyxl

Me pidieron hacer un reporte.

Definí dos vistas:

```
@login_required()
def centroCosto_carga_masivas(request):
    empresa = Empresa.objects.get(pk=request.session['id_empresa'])
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = MasivaCentroCostoForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            areas = [i for i in range(0, 100)]
            subareas = [i for i in range(0, 200)]
            wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
            ws = wb.active
            ws.title = 'areas'
            ws.append(['Nombre', 'Codigo', 'Estado'])
            n_areas = len(areas) + 1
            for area in areas:  # Aqui seria hacer un for sobre la áreas
                ws.append(
                    [f'Opcion {area}', 1, 'id']
                )
        return wb.save('demo.xlsx')

    else:
        form = MasivaCentroCostoForm()
    return render(request, 'principal/centro_costo_carga_masiva.html', wb.save('demo.xlsx'), locals())


@login_required()
def centro_costo_carga_masiva(request):
    return render(request, 'principal/centro_costo_carga_masiva.html', locals())
```

El problema es que no se me ejecuta la función de crear el reporte a través de un *template*.

Comment: Y qué error te da? Por favor realiza el [tour] y lee [ask]. Agrega un [example] para que sea más fácil ayudarte

Answer (score 0):

El problema en tu código es que estás llamando a la función `wb.save('demo.xlsx')` dentro del método `render()`. Esto no es correcto, ya que render() espera que le pases el nombre de una template como primer argumento, no el resultado de guardar el archivo de Excel.

Para solucionar esto, debes mover la llamada a `wb.save('demo.xlsx')` fuera del método `render()` y asegurarte de que se ejecute después de guardar el archivo. Aquí tienes una versión modificada del código:

```
@login_required()
def centroCosto_carga_masivas(request):
    empresa = Empresa.objects.get(pk=request.session['id_empresa'])
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = MasivaCentroCostoForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            areas = [i for i in range(0, 100)]
            subareas = [i for i in range(0, 200)]
            wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
            ws = wb.active
            ws.title = 'areas'
            ws.append(['Nombre', 'Codigo', 'Estado'])
            n_areas = len(areas) + 1
            for area in areas:
                ws.append(
                    [f'Opcion {area}', 1, 'id']
                )
            wb.save('demo.xlsx')  # Guardar el archivo de Excel aquí

            return render(request, 'principal/centro_costo_carga_masiva.html', locals())
    else:
        form = MasivaCentroCostoForm()

    return render(request, 'principal/centro_costo_carga_masiva.html', locals())
```

En este código, después de completar el bucle for y generar el archivo de Excel, se llama a `wb.save('demo.xlsx')` para guardar el archivo. Luego, se llama a `render()` para mostrar la plantilla `centro_costo_carga_masiva.html`.

Recuerda que también necesitas asegurarte de que tienes la librería `openpyxl` instalada en tu entorno de desarrollo para poder generar y guardar archivos de Excel.